# Paypal IPN not Verified or Invalid

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Hopefully someone will be able to help me or point me in the right direction. I have set up a Paypal IPN listener but don't seem to be getting any response (verified / invalid) back from the paypal after confirming the payment with paypal

I know the code works to some degree as the IPN History page confirms that a response was received back from the listener so paypal does not attempt to resend the message. If I place a code snippet to insert into my database outside of the verified/invalid if statement it works fine. It just does not do anything when I place the same code snippet inside the verified / invalid loop.

The PHP code I am using for the listener is as follows:

Hopefully someone will be able to help me or point me in the right direction. I have set up a Paypal IPN listener but
don't seem to be getting any response (verified / invalid) back from the paypal after confirming the payment with paypal

I know the code works to some degree as the IPN History page confirms that a response was received back from the listener
so paypal does not attempt to resend the message. If I place a code snippet to insert into my database outside of the verified/invalid
if statement it works fine. It just does not do anything when I place the same code snippet inside the verified / invalid loop.
The PHP code I am using for the listener is as follows:

```
<?php
// STEP 1 - be polite and acknowledge PayPal's notification
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
// STEP 2 - create the response we need to send back to PayPal for them to confirm that it's legit
$resp = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $parm => $var)
{
$var = urlencode(stripslashes($var));
$resp .= "&$parm=$var";
}

// STEP 3 - Extract the data PayPal IPN has sent us, into local variables
$record_id = $_POST['custom'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
// STEP 4 - Get the HTTP header into a variable and send back the data we received so that PayPal can confirm it's genuine
$httphead = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$httphead .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$httphead .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($resp) . "\r\n\r\n";

// Now create a ="file handle" for writing to a URL to paypal.com on Port 443 (the IPN port)
$errno ='';
$errstr='';

//$fh = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$fh = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
// STEP 5 - Nearly done. Now send the data back to PayPal so it can tell us if the IPN notification was genuine

if (!$fh) {
}
else {
fputs ($fh, $httphead . $resp);
while (!feof($fh))
{
$readresp = fgets ($fh, 1024);
if (strcmp ($readresp, "VERIFIED") == 0)
{

}

else if (strcmp ($readresp, "INVALID") == 0)
{

}
}
fclose ($fh);
}
?>
```

Comment: I would recommend using the [template PayPal provides](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php), or at least study it to see what's different from what you're doing here.

Comment: Alternatively, there are some solid solutions for IPN available on Packagist that you can quickly load with Composer.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have tried the same thing with the Paypal template and receive the same results. I have placed a mail function in the script to debug and it only fires if I place the code outside of the verification call to Paypal.   The mail function does not fire if placed in the "Verified" or "Invalid" loops.  I'm beginning to wonder if its my ISP who is blocking the return call back from paypal?

Comment: Can you check what version of PHP and OpenSSL you are running on your server?

Comment: According to 1nd1 my PHP version is 7.0 and the SSL version is "managed SSL". I don't think the lady I was speaking to actually understood what I was asking. Is there any way I can find out the SSL version myself? I have asked whether they are stopping the verification message getting back to my site but they didn't have a clue.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to OpenSSL.  Can you load a page with phpinfo() on it and provide that for review?

Comment: PHP Version 7.1.12. There are 2 entries for OpenSSL in the PHP info, output: One under the "Phar" section which states "OpenSSL support: disabled (install ext/openssl)" and the second detailing the author as "Stig Venaas, Wez Furlong, Sascha Kettler, Scott MacVicar". Sorry I don't know how to insert the file here for review.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Angell. My hosting ptovider are refusing to enable OpenSSL for PHP. I have tried using the "cacert.pem" file and CURL but don;t seem to be having much luck. I'm not very familiar with PHP and CURL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need a new host.  OpenSSL is a standard requirement for most things.  Very odd that they would say they can't enable it.  Sounds like maybe they just don't want to update it to the latest version for you, which means you'll need to get moved to a new server either with them or another provider.